# How to append CSV attachments to existing Google Sheet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-attachments

I currently have a function called importCSVFromGmail:

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
var threads = GmailApp.search("from:noreply@exacttarget.com");
var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

// Is the attachment a CSV file
attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
}
```

This import works, but it only grabs the most recent attachment from the specified email address and populates the Google Sheet with that, erasing the previous days import in the process.

I would like to know if the script can be altered to import all the reports received `from:noreply@exacttarget.com` and have them all displayed in the same sheet.

Please note that the first row contains header row names and is not needed from each CSV file.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You want to append csv data rather than replace existing data.

**Delete these rows**
You code includes these lines that need to be deleted:

1. `sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();`

This row deletes all the existing data from the sheet.

2. `sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);`

This defines a range that has cell "A1" at the top left, and the number of rows and columns are defined by the CSV data. By using cell A1, the data will be located at the top of the sheet.

**Replace with:**

`var LR = sheet.getLastRow();`
`sheet.getRange(LR+1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);`

LR is defined at the last row on the sheet.
Then the first row of the range is "LR+1" - the row immediately after the the last row.
So the `setValues` method will append the data to the sheet, beginning on the first row following the "Last Row".

---

**Edit: Sort by Timestamp**

Obviously you need to get the new "last row", and I get the last column too (but that could be re-used from an earlier value). This allows a range to be established `getRange()` - and then sorted (`sort`) (note that the range starts on row 2 to avoid headers).

FWIW, 1) the `sort` could be chained to the `getRange` (cutting out two lines). I didn't do that but only so that I could demonstrate/prove the range dimensions. 2) there is a sort command for sheets and also for ranges - best not to mix them up ;-)

```
  var sortLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sortLC = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var sortrange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sortLR-1,sortLC);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the sort range = "+sortrange.getA1Notation());
  sortrange.sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}]);
```

**Reference**

Range [`sort`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz !! This seems to have done the trick. However I was wondering if it is possible to instead of appending the new data to the "Last Row" if the newest data can be appended to the top. This script runs on a daily trigger, and it would be great if the newest data was on top and pushed the older data down underneath it. Does that make sense? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that’s possible; fiddlely, but possible, Another (easier/simpler/better?) alternative, is to append as above and then simply resort on the timestamp column.